# How to insert a value in a "lookup field"

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

This part works:

```
account = sf.query("SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Platform_Id__c = '%s' " %trx_platform_id)
```

I am able to get the Id and name of the Account like this:

```
accountId = account['records'][0]['Id'] 
accountName = account['records'][0]['Name']
```

This part does not work:

```
sf.Case.create({'Subject'    :case_subject, \
                'Reason'     :case_reason, \
                'Account'    :accountId})
```

Here is the error message:

```
simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://quinstreet.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Case/. Response content: [{'message': 'The value provided for foreign key reference Account is not a nested SObject', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'}]
```

"Account" is a standard lookup field on the Case object. How can I populate this field when I insert a new case record.

I googled for more than an hour couldn't find even a single example. TIA
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
change this:
'Account'    :accountId})
to this:
'AccountId'  :accountId})

I don't know why this works since AccountId is not the name of a field on the Case object, but it does.